# Why Gekko can't find a solution given variables initial values

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I have an optimization problem that I'm trying to solve using Gekko.
When I'm setting initial values for the variables, with values of a possible solution, which satisfied the constrains, Gekko can't find a solution. How can I find the root cause?

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Exception: Access Violation
At line 1341 of file MUMPS/src/dmumps_part2.F
Traceback: not available, compile with -ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full

Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for additional error details
did not managed to solve
((1)*((d_t200_3_1-d_t100_3_1)))
```

Here is the optimization model I'm running

```
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.options.MAX_ITER=1000
m.options.IMODE=3 

d_t200_3_0 = m.Var(540, name='d_t200_3_0')
d_t200_3_2 = m.Var(180, name='d_t200_3_2')
d_t200_3_1 = m.Var(360, name='d_t200_3_1')
d_t100_3_0 = m.Var(60, name='d_t100_3_0')
d_t100_3_2 = m.Var(20, name='d_t100_3_2')
d_t100_3_1 = m.Var(40, name='d_t100_3_1')
m.Equation(m.abs2(d_t100_3_0) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(d_t100_3_0))
m.Equation(m.abs2(d_t100_3_2) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(d_t100_3_2))
m.Equation(m.abs2(d_t100_3_1) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(d_t100_3_1))
m.Equation(m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_3_2)) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_3_2)))
m.Equation(m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_3_1)) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_3_1)))
m.Equation(m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_3_2) - -1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_3_1)) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_3_2) - -1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_3_1)))
m.Equation(m.abs2(d_t200_3_0) >= 200.0)
m.Equation(600 > m.abs2(d_t200_3_0))
m.Equation(m.abs2(d_t200_3_2) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(d_t200_3_2))
m.Equation(m.abs2(d_t200_3_1) >= 200.0)
m.Equation(400 > m.abs2(d_t200_3_1))
m.Equation(m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_3_2)) >= 200.0)
m.Equation(400 > m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_3_2)))
m.Equation(m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_3_1)) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_3_1)))
m.Equation(m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_3_2) - -1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_3_1)) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_3_2) - -1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_3_1)))

m.Obj(d_t200_3_2 - d_t100_3_2)
m.solve(debug =1, disp=True)
```

When solving this without initials values, I get a solution, but there is sometimes inconsistency, i.e. different solution for the same problem. Any hint why this could happen? I thought that there is some random initiation and the seed is changing, but according to the documentation the initial default values are 0.

Thanks!

Just to update that I didn't found the problem yet, but if looking on a subset of the optimization variables and corresponding constrains, I do able to get the optimization results.
here is the subset:

```
d_t200_1_0 = m.Var(180, name='d_t200_1_0')
d_t200_1_2 = m.Var(180, name='d_t200_1_2')
d_t100_1_0 = m.Var(20, name='d_t100_1_0')
d_t100_1_2 = m.Var(20, name='d_t100_1_2')
m.Equation(m.abs2(d_t100_1_0) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(d_t100_1_0))
m.Equation(m.abs2(d_t100_1_2) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(d_t100_1_2))
m.Equation(m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_1_0) - 1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_1_2)) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_1_0) - 1.0*m.abs2(d_t100_1_2)))
m.Equation(m.abs2(d_t200_1_0) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(d_t200_1_0))
m.Equation(m.abs2(d_t200_1_2) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs2(d_t200_1_2))
m.Equation(m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_1_0) - 1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_1_2)) >= 200.0)
m.Equation(400 > m.abs2(-1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_1_0) - 1.0*m.abs2(d_t200_1_2)))
```

Comment: Just to update that I didn't found the problem yet, but if looking on a subset of the optimization variables and corresponding constrains, I do able to get the optimization results.
here is the subset: 
```

```

Answer (score 0):

Switching over to `abs3()` helps to solve the problem. Also, some of the equations are not needed because they are always satisfied.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.options.MAX_ITER=1000
m.options.IMODE=3 

d_t200_3_0 = m.Var(540, name='d_t200_3_0')
d_t200_3_2 = m.Var(180, name='d_t200_3_2')
d_t200_3_1 = m.Var(360, name='d_t200_3_1')
d_t100_3_0 = m.Var(60, name='d_t100_3_0')
d_t100_3_2 = m.Var(20, name='d_t100_3_2')
d_t100_3_1 = m.Var(40, name='d_t100_3_1')

# these equations are not needed
# all values will satisfy the equation
#m.Equation(m.abs3(d_t100_3_0) >= 0.0)
#m.Equation(m.abs3(d_t100_3_2) >= 0.0)
#m.Equation(m.abs3(d_t100_3_1) >= 0.0)
#m.Equation(m.abs3(d_t200_3_2) >= 0.0)

# reform to eliminate absolute value with simple inequalities
#m.Equation(200 > m.abs3(d_t100_3_0))
#m.Equation(200 > m.abs3(d_t100_3_2))
#m.Equation(200 > m.abs3(d_t100_3_1))
#m.Equation(200 > m.abs3(d_t200_3_2))
#m.Equation(600 > m.abs3(d_t200_3_0))
#m.Equation(400 > m.abs3(d_t200_3_1))
v = [d_t100_3_0,d_t100_3_2,d_t100_3_1,d_t200_3_2,d_t200_3_0,d_t200_3_1]
b = [200,200,200,200,600,400]
for i,vi in enumerate(v):
    vi.LOWER = -b[i]
    vi.UPPER =  b[i]

m.Equation(m.abs3(d_t200_3_0) >= 200.0)
m.Equation(m.abs3(d_t200_3_1) >= 200.0)
m.Equation(m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t100_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t100_3_2)) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t100_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t100_3_2)))
m.Equation(m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t100_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t100_3_1)) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t100_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t100_3_1)))
m.Equation(m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t100_3_2) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t100_3_1)) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t100_3_2) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t100_3_1)))
m.Equation(m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_2)) >= 200.0)
m.Equation(400 > m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_2)))
m.Equation(m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_1)) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_1)))
m.Equation(m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_2) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_1)) >= 0.0)
m.Equation(200 > m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_2) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_1)))

m.Minimize(d_t200_3_2 - d_t100_3_2)
m.solve(disp=True)
```

This gives a successful solution.

```
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  0
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  172
   Intermediates:  0
   Connections  :  0
   Equations    :  129
   Residuals    :  129
 
 Number of state variables:    172
 Number of total equations: -  128
 Number of slack variables: -  90
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    -46
 
 * Warning: DOF <= 0
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.02 NLPi:    8 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    3 Obj: -2.00E+02 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:  -2.00E+02 Lowest Leaf:  -2.00E+02 Gap:   0.00E+00
Iter:     2 I:  0 Tm:      0.02 NLPi:    1 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    3 Obj: -2.00E+02 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.0469 sec
 Objective      :  -200.0000000002
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. what is the intuition behind using abs3 instead of abs 2.I understand that e abs2 returns absolute value with continuous first and second derivatives while abs3 generates the absolute value with a binary switch. when does it make sense choosing the first rater the second? Thanks!

Comment: The MPCC form (2) doesn't typically work as well when there are competing objectives for the slack variables. In those cases, I recommend the (3) option.

Comment: Thanks John! Interestingly, when changing the "reform to eliminate absolute value with simple inequalities" back to the original inequalities, the solver can't find a solution. Do you know why? what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Slack variables are a little more challenging to solve than general inequalities. I'm not sure why but it is likely because the problem is easier to solve.

Comment: I'm not sure which variables here are slack variables? I didn't explicitly used slack variables. can I re state the problem using only general inequalities?

Comment: I noticed another issue which might related to the abs functions. taking your code from this answer, and changing the internal order of this line: m.Equation(m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_0) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_2)) >= 200.0) , into this order: m.Equation(m.abs3(-1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_2) - -1.0*m.abs3(d_t200_3_0)) >= 200.0), and the problem is now not solvable. Do you have an idea why? those equations are equivalents. In the latter, changing the external abs3 into abs2 and the problem is solvable again. I'm not sure why?

Comment: No, I'm not sure why a little change like that would lead to a difference. Is there anything else that you changed?

Comment: No, and it's easily reproduceable. Something wired is going on when abs functions are involved. Is there another optimization package that you can recommend to try and compare? Thanks!

Comment: There are a few other optimization packages listed in the Gekko paper: https://www.mdpi.com/2227-9717/6/8/106  Let us know if you do try another package.